# Confidence Intervals under different conditions of Variance??

Tags: statistics

What's the difference in CI under the situation in part (a) and (b)??

A sample of 20 random streamflow observations produced a mean of 145m3/sec and a variance of 30 (m3/sec)2. What are the 95% confidence intervals on the mean assuming a normal distribution if (a) the true variance is estimated to be 30 (m3/sec)2; (b) the true variance is 30 (m3/sec)2. Discuss the reason why the confidence intervals computed for parts (a) and (b) are different.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In (a) we have an *estimate* of the true variance and is thus a random variable. Therefore, in part (a), the confidence interval for the mean will have to account for the additional variability in the estimated variance.